# setting error bar thickness in seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, linear-regression, seaborn

I would like to get fine error bars using seaborn's regplot (finer than the correlation line).

The code below (adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28050953)) sorts this out, but in a rather cumbersome way. Is there a more direct way to reach this, maybe via kws?

```
with matplotlib.rc_context({"lines.linewidth": 1}):

    sns.regplot('A', 'B', data=my_dataframe, x_jitter=10., ci=68, \
            ax=ax, x_estimator=np.mean,  \
            scatter_kws={"s":150}, \
            line_kws={"linewidth": 2 })
```

Comment: I think it's hardwired in the `seaborn` source code. See [this line](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/master/seaborn/linearmodels.py#L358) - its hardwired to be `lines.linewidth * 1.75`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a pull request incoming that I am working on that will allow you to specify the linewidth and allow you to determine if there should be caps on the error bars. See

https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/pull/898

If you clone my repository as a temporary fix, you should be able to specify it right now by adding the keyword conf_lw but I hope to have this integrated with unit tests written shortly.

Comment: Finished a new version with commits and unit tests to specify errwidth instead of conf_lw. That should allow you to change thickness. Again you can clone off of my repository, or wait for the pull request to go through.

Comment: As far as I can tell the ability to pass a conf_lw hasn't passed into regplot, as of seaborn 0.9.0, is there a different way to handle this for regplot?

Comment: Was this removed with the introduction of catplot? I'm trying to modify my errorbars exactly like David did but seeing any differences.